# Efficient video rendering in a 3D plot using animation and blitting

Tags: matplotlib, computer-vision, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-3d, feature-tracking

I'm currently doing a visualization task where I want to display a video within a 3D plot using matplotlib animation class. The purpose is to visualize feature tracking within the image.

I have a working video playing by repeatedly redrawing the figure but it works very slowly (around 1 fps) and I want to make it more efficient since I will add more drawings to the figure later.

I tried using blitting which is supposed to only draw data that has changed. I did it by settings blit=True within the animation class and reproducing what's done in the official [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html#module-matplotlib.animation) BUT the video does not appear to be playing at all. The only time it displays any images at all is when I resize the window which appears to force the window to update.

Why isn't it working? Am I going for the right approach to do it? Is there some other library than matplotlib that is more appropriate for this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import cv2 as cv


frames = []
for i in range(100):
    image = np.random.randint(0,255, size=(260,346), dtype="uint8")
    frames.append(image)

W, H = 260,346
X = np.arange(0, W)
Y = np.arange(0, H)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(0, X, Y, cstride=1, rstride=1, 
                        linewidth=1, shade=False, edgecolor='none')

clen = (W - 1) * (H - 1)

def init():
    # formatting
    ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), 
                                    np.diag([1.2, 0.8, 0.8 *
float(H) / float(W), 1]))
    ax.view_init(elev=20)
    ax.invert_zaxis()

    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.xaxis.labelpad = 20
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    ax.set_xlabel("Time [s]", fontsize=15)
    ax.set_xlim([0, 0.5])
    ax.set_ylim([0, W - 1])
    ax.set_zlim([H - 1, 0])
    return surf,

def update(image):
    print("Updated...")
    img = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) / 255
    surf.set_facecolor(img[:-1, :-1].reshape(clen, 3))
    
    return surf,


#Create the Animation object
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames, init_func = init,
                                interval=500, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I never solved this but as an alternative solution I ran ani.save("test.gif", fps=23) and the resulting gif was shown as I expected it. I guess matplotlibs are not suitable at updating large amount of data at a low frame rate.